# ArgumentMatchers for multiple calls on the same mock using Mockito 2.7.5

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am using Mockito 2.7.5. I need to mock call to a method and decide the return based upon the type of the objects the list parameter contains. I am doing this:

```
Mockito.when(generalUtilmock.isObjectEmpty(
    ArgumentMatchers.<List<AccountValidationResponseDTO>>any())
).thenReturn(true);

Mockito.when(generalUtilmock.isObjectEmpty(
    ArgumentMatchers.<List<License>>any())
).thenReturn(false);
```

My problem is that the second matcher overrides the first one i.e. I get 'false' in both the cases.

What did I do wrong or how can I make it work?

---

This is how I did it finally, as suggested by @glytching

Mockito.when(generalUtilmock.isObjectEmpty(ArgumentMatchers.>any())).thenAnswer(new Answer() {

```
public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
  Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
  // if args contains a List<License> then return false
  if(args[0] instanceof List){
    ArrayList o = (ArrayList)args[0];
    if(o!=null && !o.isEmpty()) {
      if (o.get(0) instanceof AccountValidationResponseDTO)
        return true;
      else if (o.get(0) instanceof License)
        return false;
    }
  }
  return false;
  // if args contains a List<AccountValidationResponseDTO> then return true
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that ordering (i.e. `when(...).thenReturn(true, false)`) won't suffice for you you'll have to use [`thenAnswer`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#answer_stubs) to test the given argument and return a value accordingly.

For example:

```
when(generalUtilmock.isObjectEmpty(ArgumentMatchers.<List<License>>any()))).thenAnswer(new Answer() {

    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();

        // if args contains a List<License> then return false
        // if args contains a List<AccountValidationResponseDTO> then return true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to type erasure you are effectively stubbing consecutive calls. See https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#10

`Mockito.when(generalUtilmock.isObjectEmpty(ArgumentMatchers.anyList())).thenReturn(true, false);`

should work.

Comment: how can I use it with lists?

Comment: try `any(List.class)`

Comment: But, I need the result based on the type of objects the list contains.

Comment: you don't know  in what order the method will be invoked? You can give the result based on order instead of type

Comment: also try anyList() if your mockito version supports it